# Code that exists is listed as undefined?

Tags: php

In the code I've been writing I am getting multiple undefined index errors on lines 135-154... I'm fairly certain that I've defined the necessary variables on lines 125-130. I've checked the other questions pertaining to this problem but I couldn't find any relevant information. Can anyone explain why i'm still getting this error even though I defined these variables? Any help is greatly appreciated.

> edit: the error message I'm getting is:  Notice: Undefined index:
>   grammar in C:\xamppnew\htdocs\loginSignup\teachersPage.php on line 133
>
> Notice: Undefined index: reading in
>   C:\xamppnew\htdocs\loginSignup\teachersPage.php on line 134
>
> Notice: Undefined index: writing in
>   C:\xamppnew\htdocs\loginSignup\teachersPage.php on line 135
>
> Notice: Undefined index: listening in
>   C:\xamppnew\htdocs\loginSignup\teachersPage.php on line 136
>
> Notice: Undefined index: speaking in
>   C:\xamppnew\htdocs\loginSignup\teachersPage.php on line 137
>
> Notice: Undefined index: assessment in
>   C:\xamppnew\htdocs\loginSignup\teachersPage.php on line 138
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: assessment in
>   C:\xamppnew\htdocs\loginSignup\teachersPage.php on line 150
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Progress in
>   C:\xamppnew\htdocs\loginSignup\teachersPage.php on line 152

```
<?php require_once('Connections/connection.php'); ?>
  <?php 
  session_start(); ?>
  <?php
    if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
     function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "",  $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
     {
     if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
   $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
    }

   $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?  mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

     switch ($theType) {
     case "text":
     $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
     case "long":
      case "int":
       $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
    case "double":
    $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
     break;
     case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
       break;
     case "defined":
     $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
       }
       return $theValue;
        }
          }

        $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
         if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
       $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
         }

         if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] ==  "TestResults")) {
         $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO test_results (gt, grammar, Fname, Lname, reading, writing, speaking, listening, overall) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['gt'], "int"),
                    GetSQLValueString($_POST['grammar'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Fname'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Lname'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['reading'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['writing'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['speaking'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['listening'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['overall'], "int"));

              mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
              $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
              }

           mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
           $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM test_results";
           $Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
           $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
           $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

           mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
           $query_Recordset2 = "SELECT * FROM test_results";
           $Recordset2 = mysql_query($query_Recordset2, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
           $row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2);
           $totalRows_Recordset2 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset2);

           $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM test_results";
            $Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
            $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
            $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1); 
       ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Teacher's Page</title>
       <link href="insert.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/php"/>
       <link href="ssmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
       <link href="sslayout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
       <style type="text/css">
      .boxed {
       margin: auto;
        padding: 2px;
         height: auto;
         width: 160px;
        border: medium solid #000;
        font-size: 20px;
        }
       .boxed1 {
 margin: auto;
padding: 2px;
height: 750px;
width: 700px;
border: medium solid #000;
font-size: 17px;
  }
 .boxed2 {
margin: auto;
padding: 2px;
height: auto;
width: 500px;
border: medium solid #000;
font-size: 20px;
 }
 </style>
<link href="fpdf.php"
 </head>

 <body>

  <h1 align="center">
 <style type="text/css">
  #NavBar nav .form #form1 .form tr td {
color: #FFF;
 }
 </style>

   <p align="center" class="boxed"><strong>EACAD003 – I1</strong></p>
 &nbsp;

   <?php
 $grammar = $row_Recordset1['grammar'];
 $reading = $row_Recordset1["reading"];
  $writing = $row_Recordset1["writing"];
 $listening = $row_Recordset1["listening"];
  $speaking = $row_Recordset1["speaking"];
  $assesment = $row_Recordset1["assesment"]; 

   ?>

   <?php
   $_SESSION["grammar"]  = $_POST["grammar"];
   $_SESSION["reading"]  = $_POST["reading"];
   $_SESSION["writing"]  = $_POST["writing"];
   $_SESSION["listening"]  = $_POST["listening"];
   $_SESSION["speaking"] = $_POST["speaking"];
   $_SESSION["assessment"] = $_POST["assessment"];

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
   {
   $grammar = $_POST['Grammar'];
   $reading  = $_POST['Reading'];
   $writing = $_POST['Writing'];
   $listening = $_POST['Listening'];
   $speaking= $_POST['Speaking']; 
   $assessment= $_POST['assessment'];
      }

    $Results = $grammar + $reading + $writing + $listening + $speaking +       $assessment;
    $Overall = $Results/100;
     $checkBox = implode(',', $_POST['Progress']);


    if(isset($_POST['SubmitForm']))
    { 
    $query="INSERT INTO test_results (Grammar, Reading, Writing, Listening, Speaking, Assesment, Progress) VALUES  ('$Grammar','$Reading','$Writing','$Listening','$Speaking','$assessment','" . $checkBox . "')"; 


   ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post"  name="TestResults" class="boxed1" id="TestResults">
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <div class="boxed2">
     <h3 align="center">ELIT LANGUAGE CENTRE </h3>
    <h3 align="center">TEST RESULTS </h3>
    <p align="center">
    <select name="ClassLevel" id="ClassLevel">
     <option value="Elementary 1" <?php if (!(strcmp("Elementary 1",  $row_Recordset1['ClassLevel']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Elementary  1</option>
     <option value="Elementary 2" <?php if (!(strcmp("Elementary 2", $row_Recordset1['ClassLevel']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Elementary 2</option>
     <option value="Elementary 3" <?php if (!(strcmp("Elementary 3", $row_Recordset1['ClassLevel']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Elementary 3</option>
     <option value="Intermediate 1" <?php if (!(strcmp("Intermediate 1", $row_Recordset1['ClassLevel']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Intermediate 1</option>
    <option value="Intermediate 2" <?php if (!(strcmp("Intermediate 2", $row_Recordset1['ClassLevel']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Intermediate 2</option>
    <option value="Intermediate 3" <?php if (!(strcmp("Intermediate 3", $row_Recordset1['ClassLevel']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Intermediate 3</option>
    <option value="Pre-Intermediate 1" <?php if (!(strcmp("Pre-Intermediate 1", $row_Recordset1['ClassLevel']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Pre-Intermediate 1</option>
    <option value="Pre-Intermediate 2" <?php if (!(strcmp("Pre-Intermediate 2", $row_Recordset1['ClassLevel']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Pre-Intermediate 2</option>
    <option value="Pre-Intermediate 3" <?php if (!(strcmp("Pre-Intermediate 3", $row_Recordset1['ClassLevel']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Pre-Intermediate 3</option>


    <option value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['ClassLevel']?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_Recordset1['ClassLevel'], $row_Recordset1['ClassLevel']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_Recordset1['ClassLevel']?></option>
        <?php
          }        while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1));
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
     if($rows > 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($Recordset1, 0);
  $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
      }
    ?>
        </select>
        </p>
     </div>
       <table width="632" border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
    <td width="163">First Name</td>
  <td width="260"><label for="Fname"></label>
    <input name="Fname" type="text" id="Fname" /></td>
    <td width="195"><label for="Lname"></label></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td><label for="gt"></label>
      <input name="Lname" type="text" id="Lname" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Passport No.</td>
    <td><label for="date">
      <input name="gt" type="text" id="gt" />
    </label></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date:</td>
    <td><label for="teacher_name">
      <input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
    </label></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Teacher:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="teacher_name" id="teacher_name" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label for="grammar"></label></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grammar:</td>
    <td><label for="grammar"></label>
      <input name="grammar" type="text" id="grammar" />          <strong>/35</strong></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Reading:</td>
    <td><label for="reading"></label>
      <input name="reading" type="text" id="reading" />
      <strong>/20</strong></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Writing</td>
    <td><label for="writing">
      <input name="writing" type="text" id="writing" />
    <strong>/20</strong></label></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Listening:</td>
    <td><label for="listening"></label>
      <input name="listening" type="text" id="listening" />
      <strong>/20</strong></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Speaking</td>
    <td><input name="speaking" type="text" id="speaking" />
    <strong>/20</strong></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Teacher's Assesment:</td>
    <td><label for="assesment"></label>
    <input type="text" name="assesment" id="assesment" />
    <strong>/15</strong></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label for="textfield2"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><p>
      <input name="overall" type="text" id="overall" value="<?php echo "$result" ?>"/>
      <label for="overall"></label>
      /130</p></td>
    <td><p>
      <input name="percentage" type="text" id="percentage" value="<?php echo "$Overall" ?>" />
   %</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="button" name="Calculate" id="Calculate" value="Calculate" /></td>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Teacher's Recommendation:</td>
     <td>Repeat

       </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="TestResults" />

      </form>
     <form id="form1" name="form1" method="submit" action="">
     <label for="ClassLevel"></label>
    <input type="submit" name="SubmitForm " id="SubmitForm " value="Submit Grades" />
    <br /> 
  <p>
  </p>
    </body>
   </html>
         </td>
        </form>


   <?php
   mysql_free_result($Recordset1);

   mysql_free_result($Recordset2);

  ?>
```

Comment: can you post your error here too?

Comment: Remove lines `132-134`... Also how is `$row_Recordset1` the same thing as `$_POST`?

Comment: Posted the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is using non existence variable.

Ex: Line 135-140

$_POST is not existing at initial => undefined error

Fix code as bellow:
Make sure variable existing before set it as value

```
$_SESSION["grammar"]  = isset($_POST["grammar"]) ? $_POST["grammar"] : '';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Hope it useful to you!

Comment: all of my variables are defined now, Thank you!